# Execute PHP GET dynamically

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, variables, get

I currently have a php script which is loaded by Javascript when a button is clicked.
It creates all the html content which looks like this once loaded

```
  <ul>
    <li>
        <a href='foo.php?var=abc123'>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href='foo.php?var=def123'>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

So when a link is clicked, it uses GET to send PHP variable to same script, and it brings up another list of results.

What I want to do, is when you click a link instead of going to a new page with results, it loads them below this part to result in something like this (like a treeview():

```
 <ul>
       <li>
          <a href="#" id="abc123">abc123</a>
       </li>
           <ul>
              <li>
                   <a href="#" id="jkl123">jkl123</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                   <a href="#" id="ghi123">ghi123</a>
              </li>
         </ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="def123">def123</a>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

I can get it to work if I use static variables, but i need to find a way to take the variable from the created html on click, put it into the javascript function, so it can execute the PHP script.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is too general. Show us the source code of your attempt.

Comment: do you mean the php script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're going to want to use `AJAX`:

```
     $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "yoururlhere.com",
            data: {
                someparam: "somevalue",
                param2: "anothervalue"
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (JSONdata, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // do work here on success


            }
        });
```

You can attach it to a click handler like this:

```
$("someID").on("click",function(){
event.preventDefault();
var href = $(this).attr("href");

         $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: href ,
                data: "param=value&param2=anothervalue",
                success: function (JSONdata, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    // do work here on success


                }
            });
});
```

**Update:**

Some example `HTML` to go along with the above code:

```
<a id="someID" href="yoururl.php">Click me</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah i thought I would. Ive done a small bit before but not much. Does that just go inside <script> tags? 

Also, because the php script loops around to create the page, wont this mean the variable will just be the last one it created (in my example html, "def123") ? Thats why i was trying to get it from the html.

Comment: Yes, this would go where ever any of your other `js` is located - be it in the `<script>` tags or in its own file. @ your second question, this code is using the `click` handlers - read up on them - So the code only runs when the `<a>` tag is clicked.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help here.

Just a bit confused with the "a#yourID"  bit. Could you explain what happens there. Should i have an onclick inside the <a> tags?

Comment: I'll update with some `html` to complete the example - also check out the `ajax` docs on the `jquery` site :)

Comment: @AdamConnah The update on the bottom shows the `<a>` tag, and I've updated the AJAX too, in order to show you how the two might work together.

Comment: Really appreciate your help here!

Should the ID be the same one for all the list items, or different? 

Also if i give the links a href, they  direct to a new page when clicked.

Comment: @AdamConnah you need to add `event.preventDefault();` inside the click handler - see latest update. And `ID`'s should *always* be unique. So you may have multiple click handlers. Or, you can change `id` to `class` and then you would use the `class selector` like this:  `$(".your_class_here").on("click", function(){ });`